# How to show response server [using stripe]

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm currently working with stripe checkout in front-end using i want to show the response of the server if the email exists. The server give me response in JSON in a new page but i want show the response of server in the same page.
i don't know how to do this can anyone help me and this is my code

```
<script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js"></script>
<script>
var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
  key: 'pk_test_51J5qzQJEXX4UHbjjBwNIVMIoZMmlO',
  image: '/assets/img/logo.png',
  token: function(token) {
    $("#stripeToken").val(token.id);
    $("#stripeEmail").val(token.email);
    $("#amountInCents").val(Math.floor($("#amountInDollars").val() * 100));
    $("#Payform").submit();
  }, function (data) { // data is the server response data
        if(data.status == "error") {
            document.getElementById("error-message").style.display = "block";
        }
      }
});


$('#customButton').on('click', function(e) {
    
    if(!$('#informations input[type=text]').val().length == 0 &&  !$('#informations input[type=email]').val().length == 0 && !$('#informations input[type=password]').val().length == 0 && $("#ShowSubject button").hasClass("active"))
    {
      var amountInCents = Math.floor($("#amountInDollars").val() * 100);
      var displayAmount = parseFloat(Math.floor($("#amountInDollars").html() * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
      
      // Get Total Price
      var span_text = $("#amountInDollars").text(); 
      $("#total").val(span_text); 
      var input_value = $("#total").val(); 


      // Open Checkout with further options
      handler.open({
        name: 'Caspeducation',
        description: 'Amount: ($' + displayAmount + ')',
        amount: amountInCents,
      });

      e.preventDefault();     
    }
    else {
        Swal.fire({
            icon: 'info',
            text: 'Please fill in the fields',
            confirmButtonText: 'OK',
            showClass: {
              popup: 'animated fadeInDown faster',
              icon: 'animated heartBeat delay-1s'
            },
            hideClass: {
              popup: 'animated fadeOutUp faster',
            }
        });
    }
});


// Close Checkout on page navigation
$(window).on('popstate', function() {
  handler.close();
});
</script>
```

this is my route

```
router.post('/payment/2', (req, res) => {
    config.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?', [email], function (error, results0, fields) {
        if (results0.length === 0) {
            var values = [
                [
                    req.body.name,
                    req.body.lastname,
                    username,
                    req.body.email,
                    hash,
                    3,
                    new Date(),
                    2,
                    0,
                    req.body.country,
                    req.body.company,
                    req.body.address1,
                    req.body.address2,
                    req.body.city,
                    req.body.gouvernate,
                    req.body.postal_code,
                    req.body.phone, 
                ]                            
            ];
            config.query(
                'INSERT INTO users(name, lastname , username, email, password , role_id, registration_date , usergroup_id, account_type, country, company, address1, address2, city, gouvernate, postal_code, phone) VALUES ?',
                [values],
                function (error, results, fields) {
                    console.log(results);
                    console.log(error);

                    var values = [
                        [
                            results.insertId,
                            req.body.subscription_id,
                            req.body.numberofusers,
                            new Date(),
                            end_date_yearly,
                        ]
                    ];

                    config.query('INSERT INTO subscription(user_id, subscriptiontype_id, numberofusers, start_date, end_date) VALUES ? ',
                        [values],

                        function (error, results, fields) {
                            console.log(results);
                            console.log(error);
                        });

                    // Insert transaction

                    var values = [
                        [
                            results.insertId,
                            req.body.subscription_id,
                            req.body.numberofusers,
                            new Date(),
                            end_date_yearly,
                            new Date(),
                            1,
                            stringify.total,

                        ]
                    ];

                    config.query(
                        'INSERT INTO transaction(user_id, subscriptiontype_id, numberofusers, start_date, end_date, transaction_date, transaction_status, transaction_amount) VALUES ? ',
                        [values],

                        function (error, results, fields) {
                            console.log(results);
                            console.log(error);
        
                        });



                        for(var i = 0; i < courseArray.length; i++) {
                            // Insert user level
                            console.log(courseArray[i]);
                            let levelIDs=courseArray[i][3];
                            if(levelIDs)
                            {
                                for(var j = 0;j <= levelIDs.length; j++) {
                                    var values = [
                                        [
                                            results.insertId,
                                            courseArray[i][0],
                                            levelIDs[j],
                                        ]
                                    ];
                                    config.query(
                                        'INSERT INTO userlevel(user_id, course_id, level_id) VALUES ? ',
                                        [values],

                                        function (error, results, fields) {
                                            console.log(results);
                                            console.log(error);
                                        });
                                }
                                
                            }   
                        }

                    // Send membership informations to stripe
                    config.query('SELECT * FROM subscription_type where id= ?', [subscription_id], function (error, results_subs, fields) {

                        if (results_subs.length > 0) {

                            let obj = JSON.stringify(req.body);
                            let stringify = JSON.parse(obj);
                            console.log(req.body)

                            var amount = stringify.total * 100;
                            console.log("Price: " + amount)
                            // Insert information of subscription to stripe
                            stripe.customers.create({
                                email: req.body.email,
                                source: req.body.stripeToken,
                            })
                                .then(customer => stripe.charges.create({
                                    amount,
                                    description: 'Subscription Teacher',
                                    currency: 'usd',
                                    customer: customer.id
                                })).then(function (charge) {
                                    if (charge.status == "succeeded") {
                                        res.render('client/success', {
                                            layout: 'client_layout',
                                        })
                                    } else {
                                        console.log("Error");

                                    }
                                })

                        }
                    });

            });
            
        } else {
            console.log("Email Already Exists.");
            return res.json({
                "status": "error",
                "message": "Email Already Exists."
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: How do you make the call to the stripe server ? What do you mean by "in a new page" ?

Comment: sorry a have route that's make the charge of stripe and sorry about the bad explanation the server give me a response JSON

Comment: can anyone help me please  i'm noob i steel learning

Comment: You need to move the email verification outside your post request. You can make an ajax call to check email before submitting the payment to stripe.

Comment: @TGrif can you help me with some code please i'm new at programing